# ASP.NET configuration, security part error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use Visual Studio 2010 and I have a problem when I want to add a username and a password using ASP.NET configuration and I have this error:

" Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed. "

How can I solve this?

Comment: Yeah, I dont think this is a code issue....

Comment: It's a question about a software tool used by programmers. See - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 0):

You might need to delete the

`C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS` directory.

Then try restarting your machine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much but, can I add a username and a password by another way like editing a file ( machine.config ) or anything else ??